# How to handle TCP and UDP sockets binded to the same port in a server written in C?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, unix-socket

I am a novice UNIX socket programming learner and I would like to inquire some advice on writing a server that can handle both TCP connections and UDP datagrams on the same port with a server written in C.

I was asked to write a server that could take multiple commands from clients, with the type of transport layer protocol varying between TCP and UDP based on the command sent by the client. For example, if users type a "login" command then it must be sent to the server through TCP, while a "register" command must be sent through UDP.

The typical behavior of a client is listed as below: 
  1. Create TCP and UDP sockets
  2. Connect the TCP socket to the server
  3. Based on the commands entered by the user, the message from the cilent must be sent to the server with a specified    protocol. (Example: TCP for "login", etc... ; UDP for "register", etc...)
  4. After the user enters the "exit" command, close both TCP and UDP sockets.

The partial workflow of the server I already written include:
  1. Create TCP and UDP sockets
  2. Bind TCP and UDP sockets to the same port
  3. Listen with the TCP socket
  4. Accept the TCP connection from a client
  5. ???

The uncertainties that I hold are steps starting from 5. Apparently if it were simply a TCP server I could just read from and write into the new TCP socket created with the accept() function call. However now that I have two potential sources of receiving the next message from the client, I do not know what to do to handle them both.

Thank you !

Comment: I've made this a duplicate of questions which describe how to handle multiple sockets in C within a single process. It does not matter much if this is TCP or UDP or both mixed.

Comment: TCP ports are _not_ UDP ports, despite using the same number range for the ports. TCP port 12345 is _not_ the same port as UDP port 12345. You cannot bind TCP and UDP to the same port because they are different ports, even if the port number is the same number.